# lightGallery image gallery component for angular - Close and Dowload button Icon dissapear after switching the browser to mobile screen

Tags: typescript, angular10

Whenever the screen switches to a mobile view on the browser and the refresh browser, lightGallery doesnt work propperly.

The download icon and close icon dissapear - Its not even in the HTML dom.

Herev is the example followed - source code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/lightgallery-angular-update-slides

To repoduce this behaviour, Open below link on a new tab. Then switch to a mobile view, then refrech the browser.

https://lightgallery-angular-update-slides.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add mobileSettings object when initializing settings for gallery

```
ngOnInit(): void {



    this.settings = {
      addClass: "lg-update-slide-demo",
      autoplayFirstVideo: false,
      pager: false,
      galleryId: "nature",
      thumbnail: true,
      plugins: [lgZoom, lgThumbnail, lgFullScreen, lgAutoplay],
      mobileSettings: {
        controls: true,
        showCloseIcon: true,
        download: true,
        rotate: true
      },
    }
}
```